# In javascript does script tag onload Event be triggered before a mutation observer can see it?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers, script-tag

In javascript does script tag onload Event be triggered before an observer can intercept it ?

Comment: onload doesn't imply mutation. On the other hand, an onload callback can cause a mutation.

Comment: The order of invocation may be browser-dependent so you need to verify it yourself. Doing it should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

So after some tests, the observer triggers first :-)